# MVC 5 DropwnListFor not showing selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

We have a project which we just migrated from MVC 4 to MVC 5 but now started facing this issue.
We have used @Html.DropDownListFor on several places which used to work previously, but now with MVC 5, all drop downs has stopped showing selected value. (If SelectListItem has Selected=true).
I found similar issue posted here [ASP.NET MVC 5 DropDownListFor not selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109118/asp-net-mvc-5-dropdownlistfor-not-selected)
Anyone facing same issue?

Answer (score 0):

in view

```
<td colspan="2">
                    @Html.DropDownList("DpTemp", "Select")
                </td>
```

In Controller

```
 ViewData["DpTemp"] = new SelectList(objCountry22.CountrySearchResult, "CountryName", "CountryName", 0).ToList();
```

Using ViewData you can fill your dropdownlist but you must have to maintain ViewData's and DropDownList Name same.

Comment: indeed, passing a model to a view is better but it looks right